# How to prevent rm from reporting that a file was not found in CURL?

Tags: bash, curl, rm

When executing the command

```
curl  -k HOST --user user:pass -Q "rm nosuch"
```

I get an answer

```
curl: (21) rm command failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried using -f, but the result hasn't changed

```
curl -f -k HOST --user user:pass -Q "rm -f nosuch"

curl: (21) rm command failed: No such file or directory
```

How do I exclude a message?

Comment: Are you asking how you can stop the error message from echoing back to the terminal or why the error is occuring?

Comment: @RamanSailopal, ignore the error message. -s helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
curl -s, --silent
```

See [curl - man](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)